# GLSL Wrong Color Value

Tags: opengl, colors, glsl

I seem to have run into a strange situation here, because no-one else seems to have the same problem according to various searches in various places. Most of the questions relate to blending or lighting or any variety of other tasks... in my case, the problem exists as a coloring flaw.

I'm wanting the shader to provide an exact color; that is, if I screenshot the thing I'm working on and use a color-picker, I want it to show up with the same color I'm using in code. Seems simple enough, right?

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 175.0 / 255.0, 50.0 / 255.0, 1.0);
}
```

Also simple enough, right? Now, before someone yells "It's the dividing! It won't get it perfectly at your number!" I've tested with greyscale and found a way to make it 100% accurate with shades of grey, but something strange happens with color... I use this and, when I screenshot and use a color picker, I get: R: 68, G: 166, B: 45

Now, I'm not a mathematical genius, but I'm pretty sure 0.0 with no additional editing is flat 0 for red. Before this, I was trying to pass in a uniform color, so I started looking through my code to see if it was something strange I was doing, even though I was 95% sure I wasn't. Then I just replaced everything with this set-in-stone, hardcoded vec4 to see if IT came up with the right information.

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm getting the strange red value, and perhaps why the other two values aren't QUITE there? Sure, they're close... but I'd like to get even closer; exact, if at all possible.

EDIT:
So... I'm not entirely familiar with glReadPixels, so if I did this wrong, let me know. However, my results are what I expect the output to be.

```
GLfloat *data = new GLfloat[4];
    if (data)
    {
        glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
        std::cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " " << data[2] << " " << data[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << data[0] * 255.0 << " " << data[1] * 255.0 << " " << data[2] * 255.0 << " " << data[3] * 255.0 << std::endl;
        delete data;
    }
```

Shader: 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0

RGBA from ReadPixels: 0, 0, 1, 1

Shader: 0.0, 175.0 / 255.0, 50.0 / 255.0, 1

RGBA from ReadPixels: 0, 0.686275, 0.196078, 1

RGBA from ReadPixels multipled by 255: 0, 175, 50, 255

Comment: I don't think this can be answered with anything but guesses without looking at more code. What about other values like (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), does that work as expected? Do you use blending? What's the clear color? You're rendering to the default framebuffer?

Comment: 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 results in 242, 61, 46 in color picker. 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 results in 104, 242, 0. 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 results in 0, 72, 253. That's literally all that's being done in GLSL. There aren't any changes, adjustments, no effects whatsoever. I'm using a VBO quad that covers the entire screen, so it's a solid whatever-color quad. So, what exactly would help figure the problem out? I'm using GL_BLEND with glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), which to my understanding just blends transparency - and commenting it out doesn't change anything. Yes, default framebuffer.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention the clear color: It's completely black. 0, 0, 0, 1. But as a note, I changed this to pure white and it didn't make a difference. Setting the alpha to 0 for the clear color also didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try using glReadPixels and check what color is reported by the GL?

Comment: I didn't before, but it seems to get the correct values - updated the post for that, though, because that's probably a good thing to test with.

Comment: Then looks like another application and not OpenGL is making those changed, such as the compositor, or even the color picker could be wrong, there is not enough information to tell.

Comment: I'm using GIMP on Mac/Mountain Lion for the color-picker. If it's GIMP, though, then its entire color system is wrong. I typed in the values and flooded an empty image and compared. There is a noticeable difference between the two sight-wise. I really have no idea what information would be useful; if you have specifics in mind, feel free to ask and I'll find the answers. Generally when dealing with a color, it's effectively four variables that determine a finalized number, and as I've said, there's nothing I've adjusted whatsoever. The only 'unique' thing I'm using: GLKit for modelview matrix.

Comment: Well what you are doing sounds wrong, because the GL values are correct, but getting them from "outside GL" can cause that those values be different. In your case, the GL output is processed by the Mac OS X compositor, and it can make changes to those values (for example, color calibration, gamma correction, etc).

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that and/or would it be reasonable to do so?